# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd capture verbose output

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to capture the verbose output from the Invoke-Sqlcmd in Powershell. Anyone got any ideas to do this:

i.e.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Query "PRINT 'Hello World!';" -ServerInstance $Server -verbose  > D:\SqlLog.txt
```

The SqlLog.txt file should contain the text "Hello World!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since capturing verbose output is not something one can do easily through the native constructs of the PowerShell host, you can always use the programatic access to the [PowerShell object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144526(v=VS.85).aspx). You can then gain access to the five different streams of information:

```
> $ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
> [ref]$e = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException
> $ps.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn( "SqlServerCmdletSnapin100", $e ) | Out-Null
> $ps.AddCommand( "Invoke-Sqlcmd" ).AddParameter( "Query", "Print 'hello world'" ).AddParameter( "Verbose" )
> $ps.Invoke()
> $ps.Streams

Error    : {}
Progress : {}
Verbose  : {hello world}
Debug    : {}
Warning  : {}

> $ps.Streams.Verbose | % { $_.Message | Out-File -Append D:\SqlLog.txt }
> cat D:\SqlLog.txt

hello world
```

Answer (score 19):

According to [Capture Warning, Verbose, Debug and Host Output via alternate streams](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/297055/capture-warning-verbose-debug-and-host-output-via-alternate-streams):

> ...if I wanted to capture verbose output in a script:
>
> stop-process -n vd* -verbose 4>&1 > C:\Logs\StoppedProcesses.log

So, you would do something like

```
(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "PRINT 'Hello World!';" -ServerInstance $Server -verbose) 4> c:\temp\myoutput.txt
```

Where 4 is the "verbose" stream.

Answer (score 10):

Please try:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Query "PRINT 'Hello World!';" -ServerInstance $Server -verbose  > D:\SqlLog.txt  2>&1
```

[I found it at](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_Pipes_and_Redirection)

Answer (score 4):

So I know this is a little unrelated, but I needed to capture "RAISERROR" and "PRINT" statements in a separate variable then the row data.  Here is how I did it:
`$Messages = %{ $Rows = Invoke-Sqlcmd  -Query "PRINT 'Hello World!';" -ServerInstance $Server -verbose} 4>1`

It row data from Invoke-SqlCmd is on STDOUT which is consumed by $Rows the verbose output continues on the pipe and is redirected into STDOUT (which, thanks to $Rows is empty).  The only thing in STDOUT to hand to $Messages is the Verbose output.  Whew!

It's a little further complicated in that to get to the data it's now on $Messages.Message.

Comment: Ugh! sorry so long.  Looks like my ampersands did not make it during the paste.  The `4>1` should have been `&4>&1`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want print statements, just add -Verbose at the end of the command.

Eg.
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -ServerInstance $Server -Database "master" -Verbose

May be able to use that in combination with Out-File:-

Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\MyFolder\TestSQLCmd.sql" | Out-File -filePath "C:\MyFolder\TestSQLCmd.rpt"

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx

Comment: How does that help the OP pipe verbose output to a file?

Comment: does not work with backup: ``-Query "BACKUP DATABASE [$p2] TO DISK=`'$p5\$p6`' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = `'$p2-Full Database Backup`', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10" -verbose | Out-File -filePath "$p5\info.txt"  but works with  *>

Answer (score 3):

For me the below command worked:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "C:\cfn\scripts\set-tempdb.sql" -Verbose *> "C:\cfn\log\set-tempdb.log"
```

I am using Powershell 5.1 on Windows 2016 With SQL Enterprise 2016

Answer (score 3):

I think there is an easier solution.  I was struggling to output both the verbose stream to the console real-time and also save it as a variable to use further downstream in my script.

`` Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query `
              -Database $Database `
              -ServerInstance $ServerInstance `
              -Verbose 4>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable output ``

`4>&1` redirects the verbose stream to the main output steam
`Tee-Object` allows the pipeline to output to two different places, in this case the invoke-sqlcmd is outputting to console but is saving to a variable as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell 3, *>> appends all output (including verbose) to a file

```
'Running sql query:'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance .\sql -Verbose -Query "Print 'hello world'" *>> c:\temp\sql.log
'Display file content:'
Get-Content c:\temp\sql.log | Out-Host
```

Answer (score 1):

Capturing verbose output is tricky. The only post I've seen on this topic is here:
http://www.nivot.org/2009/08/19/PowerShell20AConfigurableAndFlexibleScriptLoggerModule.aspx

An easier option would be to no use verbose and convert to write-output. You could modify invoke-sqlcmd2 function to use write-output instead http://poshcode.org/2279

Comment: Simmo: I've done it by using start-transcript and stop-transcript... it seems to capture everything that would have gone to the terminal

Comment: Good idea. I hadn't thought of start-transcript.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture output to a variable instead of redirecting it to a file.

```
invoke-sqlcmd "select 13.0/7.0" |out-string -outvariable abc
$abc
```

produces:

```
 Column1
 -------
1.857142
```

Answer (score 0):

I use both combination of -IncludeSqlUserErrors and -ErrorVariable truc

```
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $instance -Database 'master' -Query "select @@version" -IncludeSqlUserErrors -ErrorVariable truc

Write-Host $truc
```