# SQL Server 2008: how to get the "Messages" tab (in Management Studio) output with powershell

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I am using `invoke-sqlcmd` to manage my databases, it works fine.
I save the output of the "Results" tab in Management Studio to a log file.

When I do a `BACKUP DATABASE`, the output is done on the "Messages" tab and I would like to save it in the logfile.

Is there a way to get that output ? (or a table in SQL Server 2008 that stores the backup progression and results ?)

The SQL Server 2008 logs contain something but it is not as verbose as the "Messages" tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Invoke-Sqlcmd does not display
>   messages, such as the output of PRINT
>   statements, unless you specify the
>   Windows PowerShell -Verbose common
>   parameter. For example:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "PRINT N'abc';" -Verbose
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx)

Comment: Note: running get-help invoke-sqlcmd returns help information which also states this info. The only reason I mention this--get-help is a great place to start when you have questions one specific cmdlets.

Comment: I got the output on the console, but nothing in my log file. Another   error in my script ?  

`invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "myPC\SQLEXPRESS2K8" -Query "BACKUP DATABASE test333 TO DISK = N'c:\Backup\test333.bak' WITH FORMAT, STATS = 10" -Verbose | Out-File -filePath "c:\tmp\ps.txt"`

Comment: See [connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/390263/invoke-sqlcmd-should-have-ability-to-capture-verbose-output) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511498/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-capture-verbose-output)

Comment: great links ! Thanks and sorry for not finding that answer :p

Answer (score 2):

A working example if it can help someone :

```
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
[ref]$e = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException
$ps.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn( "SqlServerCmdletSnapin100", $e ) | Out-Null
$ps.AddCommand( "Invoke-Sqlcmd" ).AddParameter( "Verbose" ).AddParameter( "ServerInstance", "localhost\SQLEXPRESS2K8" ).AddParameter( "Query", "BACKUP DATABASE xxx TO DISK = N'c:\tmp\xxx.bak' WITH FORMAT, STATS = 10" )
$ps.Invoke()
$ps.Streams.Verbose | % { $_.Message} | Out-File c:\tmp\ps002.txt
cat c:\tmp\ps002.txt
```