# Formatting the verbose output of a Remove-Item command

Tags: powershell

I have the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem $build_path `
    -Include *.bak, *.orig, *.txt, *.chirp.config `
    -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose
```

to clear some files from the build folder of a VS solution. I use the Verbose switch so that I can see which files are being deleted. It works fine but the output is too verbose:

```
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Remove File" on Target "R:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomeProject\SomeProject.Web.build\App_Readme\glimpse.mvc3.readme.txt".
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Remove File" on Target "R:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SomeProject\SomeProject.Web.build\App_Readme\glimpse.readme.txt".
```

I just need to see something like that:

```
Removing file \App_Readme\glimpse.mvc3.readme.txt".
Removing file \App_Readme\glimpse.readme.txt".
...
```

I know i can do this with a foreach statement and a Write-Host command, but I believe it can be done with some pipelining or something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `ForEach-Object` is pretty straightforward:

```
Get-ChildItem $build_path `
    -Include *.bak, *.orig, *.txt, *.chirp.config `
    -Recurse | foreach{ "Removing file $($_.FullName)"; Remove-Item $_}
```

As @user978511 pointed out, using the verbose output is more complicated:

```
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()

$null = $ps.AddScript(@'
    Get-ChildItem $build_path `
        -Include *.bak, *.orig, *.txt, *.chirp.config `
        -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose
'@)

$ps.Invoke()
$ps.Streams.Verbose -replace '(.*)Target "(.*)"(.*)','Removing File $2'
```

Comment: `FullName` is required.
`Remove-Item $_.FullName;` is actually do the job without exception.

Answer (score 4):

In PowerShell 3.0 you can write the Verbose stream to the output stream (e.g 4>&1) and then replace the message:

```
Get-ChildItem $build_path `
    -Include *.bak, *.orig, *.txt, *.chirp.config `
    -Recurse | Remove-Item -Verbose 4>&1 | Foreach-Object{ `
        Write-Host ($_.Message -replace'(.*)Target "(.*)"(.*)','Removing File $2') -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a few years too late but it might help someone else who stumbles upon this like I did so I'll provide it anyway.

I would try the file deletion and then report on success or failure. See below:

```
$FileList = $build_path `
    -Include *.bak, *.orig, *.txt, *.chirp.config `
    -Recurse

foreach ($File in $FileList)
{
    Try
    {
        Remove-Item $File.FullName -Force -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Output "Deleted: $($File.Parent)\$($File.Name)"
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Output "Error deleting: $($File.Parent)\$($File.Name); Error Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

If you wanted to both output to console and log to a file you can use *Tee-Object* at the end of each line starting with *Write-Output* above.

```
| Tee-Object -FilePath $your_log_file -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to modify the message you need first to cath the output that is not that easy. You can refer to answer on this page:
[Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd capture verbose output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511498/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-capture-verbose-output)
to catch the output. From there on you can modify the message and show it in your format, but foreach options looks easier to me