# What is the invoke-sqlcmd verbose output to file syntax?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, sqlcmd, verbose

I currently have:

```
(invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile (Join-Path $FileDirectory $FileName) -ServerInstance $ServerName -verbose) > $OutFileName
```

To which I'm getting the output:

```
VERBOSE: Changed database context to 'BLUELABEL'
```

I'm trying to use the verbose output to write to the file designated by the Join-Path function.

What am I doing wrong?

(Using PowerShell V3)

I did find this question with answers, but it seems different and I can't seem to apply the same ideas: [Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd capture verbose output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511498/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-capture-verbose-output)

Comment: **What am I doing wrong?** Not giving `$OutFileName` a value. Question is, why do you want to write to the file that contains the sql command you're executing?

Comment: I'm sorry this is just the portion that I output on, please assume all variables are properly assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting

```
sqlps -Command "&{invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $file) -ServerInstance $server -verbose}" *> "$PSScriptRoot\SqlLog_$file`_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss).txt"
```

to work.

Originally I was calling another script and passing in 3 variables to it, and running the invoke-sqlcmd call.  For some reason that caused me to be unable to use the "*>" or any character combined with the ">".

Maybe someone else can elaborate on why exactly this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Verbose output is written to a different stream than regular output. The `>` operator redirects only the success output stream. To redirect the verbose output stream you need

```
(...) 4> $OutFileName
```

or

```
(...) 4>&1 > $OutFileName
```

if you want to combine success and verbose output streams.

See [about_Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) for further information.

Comment: Trying both of the suggested solutions I get the following error:

`4 : Unexpected token '4' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (4:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken`