# Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd doesn't capture all verbose output

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-2.0, invoke-sqlcmd

I created following powershell (v2) script to execute query on target database and build another query/queries to be run:

```
$sql = @"
DECLARE @Tables CURSOR;
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(200);

BEGIN
    SET @Tables = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM test.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'x%'

    OPEN @Tables 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Tables 
    INTO @TableName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM test.dbo.' + @TableName
        FETCH NEXT FROM @Tables 
        INTO @TableName 
    END; 

    CLOSE @Tables ;
    DEALLOCATE @Tables;
END;
"@
$ps = [PowerShell]::Create()
$ps.AddCommand("Invoke-Sqlcmd").AddParameter("Query", $sql).AddParameter("Verbose")
$ps.Invoke()

$sqlOutput = $ps.Streams.Verbose
$sqlOutputToRun = $nul
$sqlOutput | foreach {
    $sqlOutputToRun += ($_.ToString() + "`n")
}
$sqlOutputToRun = @"
$sqlOutputToRun
"@

$sqlOutputToRun
```

In the end of script I am printing queries that have to be executed, but unfortunately variable $sqlOutputToRun contains only about 3/4 expected output. 
I suppose that output is somehow cut because of the size, but I am not sure how I can  extend it.

Do you know what is missing?

Comment: Why use a `CURSOR` to do this? Why not use the `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` method to do this in one hit?

Comment: I pasted you only part of the script. Script contains many more operations and cursors are more flexible for me to handle it, but it's redundant information for describing this issue.

Comment: Why are you invoking PowerShell in a new environment, rather than just calling `Invoke-Sqlcmd` (or `sqlcmd.exe`, if you need pure textual output) directly and piping the output?

Comment: Because I couldn't get output of query. Output contains text generated by PRINT command and not just results from database. This is the only solution I found (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511498/powershell-invoke-sqlcmd-capture-verbose-output)

Comment: OK, then my obvious next question would by why you're using `PRINT` instead of `SELECT` to capture the output as a proper result set, which is actually what `Invoke-Sqlcmd` is designed to work with. `PRINT` has its own issues with strings getting cut off. (Having said that, `Invoke-Sqlcmd` may not handle multiple result sets correctly -- per Larnu, if you can't fit it all in one query, consider inserting intermediate results in a table variable, then selecting that at the end of everything, which is still easier than capturing `PRINT` statements.)

Comment: Because I have to build a kind of dynamic query depending on multiple conditions, flags, table states, etc. It's a generic solution that avoids many manual steps.

Comment: Fine, but even if you're married to a cursor loop, replacing `PRINT` with `INSERT @queries(query) SELECT 'MySuperDuperDynamicQuery'` and doing `SELECT * FROM @queries` at the end should be a valid approach in that case. In my experience, when you're having any kind of trouble with `PRINT`, the problem is usually that you're using `PRINT`.

Comment: Well, I have a query that builds script for replication. This query is tested and works fine by long time. The benefits are: query builds the output query (that can be shared) and builds query dynamically based on some db conditions. 
I agree that it might not be the best solution, but for now I was just looking for the solution that let me live with it without any SQL script modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't live without your cursor why you can't do something like this?

```
$sql = "
DECLARE @Tables CURSOR;
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(200);
DECLARE @Results TABLE (ResultQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

BEGIN
    SET @Tables = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM testdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    --AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'x%'

    OPEN @Tables 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Tables 
    INTO @TableName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Results (ResultQuery)
        SELECT 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM test.dbo.' + @TableName

        -- PRINT 'SELECT TOP 1 * FROM test.dbo.' + @TableName
        FETCH NEXT FROM @Tables 
        INTO @TableName 
    END; 

    CLOSE @Tables ;
    DEALLOCATE @Tables;
END;
SELECT * FROM @Results;"
$sqlOutputToRun = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $sql
$sqlOutputToRun
```

Answer (score 1):

And once you dump the `print` statements in favor of a resultset, you can dump the cursor too, and just run a simple query like:

```
    select 'SELECT TOP (1) * FROM '+ quotename(table_catalog) + '.' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'x%'
```

so in Powershell:

```
$sql = @"
        select 'SELECT TOP (1) * FROM '+ quotename(table_catalog) + '.' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
       -- AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'x%'
"@

$sqlOutputToRun = $nul

invoke-sqlcmd $sql | foreach { 
     $sqlOutputToRun += $_[0] + "`n"
}

$sqlOutputToRun
```